# Using a variable as range selection criterion for the AVERAGEIF function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to take the average of a number of cells, with the criterion being that their values must be between two values given in two other cells (minimum and maximum value). When I try to implement this directly (using AND(A1)) i get the #DIV/0 error, so no cells have been selected.

How can I accomplish this without manually typing in the boundary values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution, courtsey of Reddit user [excelevator](https://www.reddit.com/user/excelevator):

First of all, use the AVERAGEIFS function if there are multiple criteria involved.
Second, use `"ComparativeOperator"&CellID` for the argument.

Example: `=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A100;B1:B100;">="&C1;B1:B100;"<="&D1)`